Run multiple dotnet projects that share library in VS Code
I have 3 projects in my solution - Blazor WASM, Api server and shared library (referenced from both - blazor and api). When I ran api (or blazor) everything works fine - it builds shared library, builds api (or blazor) and run api (or blazor).
But I created a compound configuration, where I ran api and blazor at the same time. At this moment it builds api and blazor and both try to build shared library at the same time. Sometimes it works fine, sometime I've got an error: Cannot open '<path_to_lib>\Shared.dll' for writing -- 'The process cannot access the file '<path_to_lib>\Shared.dll' because it is being used by another process.'.
This is my launch.json file:
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "API - Launch",
      "type": "coreclr",
      "request": "launch",
      "preLaunchTask": "API - build",
      "program": "${workspaceFolder}/API/bin/Debug/net8.0/API.dll",
      "args": [],
      "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/API",
      "stopAtEntry": false,
      "env": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "Blazor - Launch and Debug",
      "type": "blazorwasm",
      "request": "launch",
      "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/Blazor",
      "preLaunchTask": "Blazor - build",
    }
  ],
  "compounds": [
    {
      "name": "Launch All",
      "configurations": [
        "API - Launch",
        "Blazor - Launch and Debug"
      ]
    }
  ]
}

Is there any way to not build shared library twice? Or to wait one build for another?
